# Overloading the << operator to print out a std::list

Tags: c++, list, iterator, std

I've been having some problems trying to implement an overloaded << operator function that can print out a std::list which is a member of one of my classes. The class looks like this:

```
class NURBScurve {
  vector<double> knotVector;
  int curveOrder;
  list<Point> points;
public:
  /* some member functions */
  friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const NURBScurve& curve);
};
```

The key member variable I am interested in is the list of "Points" - this is another class that I have created which stores coordinates of a point along with associated member functions. When I try and implement the overloaded << operator function as:

```
ostream& operator<<( ostream &out, const NURBScurve &curve)
{
 out << "Control points: " << endl;
 list<Point>::iterator it;
 for (it = curve.points.begin(); it != curve.points.end(); it++)
    out << *it; 
 out << endl;
 return out;
}
```

I start to get problems. Specifically, I get the following error:
error:

```
no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘it = curve->NURBScurve::points. std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin [with _Tp = Point, _Alloc = std::allocator<Point>]()’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_list.h:113: note: candidates are: std::_List_iterator<Point>& std::_List_iterator<Point>::operator=(const std::_List_iterator<Point>&)
```

I'm a bit stumped here, but I believe it has something to do with the list iterator I am using. I'm also not too confident with the notation of curve.points.begin().

If anyone can shed some light on the problem I would appreciate it. I'm at the point where I've been staring at the problem for too long!

Comment: You could give the [pretty printer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers) a try :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`curve` is const-qualified, so `curve.points` is const-qualified and `curve.points.begin()` returns a `std::list<Point>::const_iterator`, not a `std::list<Point>::iterator`.

Containers have two `begin()` and `end()` member functions:  one pair are not const-qualified member functions and return `iterator`s, the other pair are const-qualified and return `const_iterator`s.  This way you can iterate over a container that is not const and both read and modify the elements in it, but you can also iterate over a const container with read-only access.

Comment: I don't know how you replied as fast as you did, but you are completely right, and this has fixed my problem. I suppose this has highlighted my lack of understanding of the std library, but I'll keep cracking on... Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Or,

You could use `std::copy` as:

```
std::copy(points.begin(), points.end(), 
                      std::ostream_iterator<Point>(outStream, "\n"));
```

Make sure the signature of `operator<<` is this:

```
std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream &out, const Point &pt);
                                            //^^^^^ note this
```